# fprintf error trying to print 2 vectors in a file (not defined for a cell?)

Tags: matlab

I have 2 vectors, one is a dictionary of words of length 147202x1 like this

```
hello
there
some_word
...
```

The other vector is a list of numbers like this with the same length

```
1.0
-1.0
1.0
...
```

I would like to make a sample of this with random numbers. I make this new vector of length 1437

```
x_1 = randsample(1:length(dictS_train), 1437, true);
```

I think that this is a sample of numbers between 1 and length(dictS_train) of length 1437. I want to print these new vectors in a file. So I tried

```
filename = 'name_of_the_file.txt';
filename = fopen(filename,'w');
fprintf(filename,'%s %f \n', dictS_train(x_1), polS_train(x_1));
fclose(filename);
```

But the problem is that it pops this error

> Function fprintf is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

What I am doing wrong? Maybe I have to print one by one each number?

Just in case, I want to print in each line one element of dictS_train and other of polS_train

Comment: What you're doing wrong is spelled out quite clear for you by MATLAB: you can't use `fprintf` on a cell. Either make it a matrix (doubtful it'll work in your case), or loop over it, extracting each cell element to a temporary char-matrix one.

Comment: And how I do the second? I tried to pass to other new vector with `x = dictS_train(x_1);`
`y = polS_train(x_1);`
 `for k=1:length(x_1)`
  `fprintf(filename,'%s %f \n', x(k), y(k));`             
   `end` 
   But I obtain the same error

Comment: You are trying to call a cell as a regular matrix (with round brackets `()`). You shouldn't to this. You'd better read up on the [language fundamentals of data types in MATLAB](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-types_data-types.html) as this is a very elemental thing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was making a mess with each data type.

If someone has the same problem, an easy solution is to see if your data is a cell with `class(your_data)`. If says it is a cell, then you can change to an simple array (vector) with `cell2mat(your_data)`. But watch out if the dimensions are of an array.

For example, mine were (n,1), so I have to change it with " ' " to (1,n) like this:`cell2mat(your_data')`

Comment: `cell2mat` is only going to work if your cells contain uniform data of uniform size.